# Creating a website on the fly using getElementById?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a web site on-the-fly using JavaScript, but can't get my getElementById function to work properly.  I've poked around a good bit and found examples and try w/o success to make them work(the majority of them did not use an external .js file).  Below is the code my JavaScript and HTML:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Final Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="finalProj.js">
</script>
<form name = "myForm">
<h1 id="myHeader"></h1>
```

JavaScript:

```
var firstName = ("RicK");
var courseName = ("WEB 180");

function myHeading()
{
document.getElementById('header').write = (firstName + lastName);
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the `myHeading` function anywhere ?

Answer (score 6):

1. The JavaScript code that should have access to certain DOM elements, has to come **after** the elements in HTML, otherwise the elements are not generated in DOM yet (assuming the JavaScript code you wrote is in `finalProj.js`):

   ```
   <body>
      <form name = "myForm">
          <h1 id="myHeader"></h1>
      </from>
      <!-- can access myHeader now -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="finalProj.js"></script>
   </body>
   ```
2. Don't know about a *`write`* property, but [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aelement.innerHTML) should do it:

   ```
   document.getElementById('myHeader').innerHTML = firstName + lastName;
   ```

   And of course you have to call `myHeading()` too!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('myheader').innerHTML = "(" + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ")";
```

?

Answer (score 2):

The ID you specified and the ID of the header it looks like you are trying to select don't match.  You have:

```
<h1 id="myHeader"></h1>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('header').write = (firstName + lastName);
```

You need to change that to:

```
document.getElementById('myHeader').write = (firstName + lastName);
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
var firstName = "RicK";
var courseName = "WEB 180";

function myHeading() {
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The property you want is `innerHTML` (and you can omit the parenthesis):

```
document.getElementById('myHeader').innerHTML = firstName + lastName;
```